# awk: deal with newline separation in wrong place

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, newlines

I have some data that looks like this:

```
abc


123
456
789
def


111
222
333
ghi


999
888
777
666
```

i.e. the records are separated by multiple newlines but in the wrong place. What I want is to get it like this:

```
abc
123
456
789

def
111
222
333

ghi
999
888
777
666
```

I have tried setting `RS` to `\n\n\n` in awk but that ends up with the records cut up wrong; the `abc` term ends up as the final field of the previous record rather than the first field of the current record.

I'm not sure how to use `sed` for this either since that works on a line-by-line basis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
awk '!NF {next} /[^0-9]/ {printf XRS; XRS = ORS} 1' file2
abc
123
456
789

def
111
222
333

ghi
999
888
777
```

It deletes empty lines (I read from your spec that those are really empty, no spaces etc.), then checks if there is any non-digit, indicating record headers, for which it prints a newline except for the first one which gets an empty string.

Comment: Don't use all upper case for user-defined variable names to avoid clashing with builtin names and so it doesn't obfuscate your code by making it look like you're using builtin names when you aren't.

Answer (score 5):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk '/[^0-9]/ && NR>1{print ""} NF' file
abc
123
456
789

def
111
222
333

ghi
999
888
777
666
```

Answer (score 3):

GNU sed:

```
sed '1b;/^$/d;/[a-z]/s/^/\n/' file
```

If there is a letter in the string, insert a newline before it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that we want to change: **[line][emptylines][lines] --> [emptylines][line][lines]**, you could run something along the lines of

```
perl -00pe's/(\S.*\n)((\h*\n)+)/$2$1/' ex1
```

(this is independent of line contents (integer vs noninteger))

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` :

```
sed -n '/^$/d;/^[0-9]*$/{h;n;//!ba;x;G;;p;d};p;d;:a H;g;s/\n/\n\n/;p;' sample.txt
```

Using `awk` :

```
awk '
         NF && /^[0-9]*$/{f = 1;print} 
         NF && f && /^[^0-9]*$/{print "\n" $0; f = 0} 
         NR == 1
   ' sample.txt
```

Using `perl` :

```
perl -alne 'if(/^\S/){$_ = (/^\d/ || $. == 1) ? $_ : "\n$_";print}' sample.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `perl` in paragraph mode (-00) where
all  consecutive newlines are squashed into one.

```
$ perl -lp -00e 's/(?=\n[a-z])/\n/' file
```

---

Using GNU sed:

```
$ sed -e '/[a-z]/{H;1h;z;x;}' -e '/./!d' file
```

---

```
awk 'BEGIN{a[1]=ORS}
/[a-z]/ && sub(/^/,a[!!k++]) || NF
' file
```

Using GNU awk with regexified input record separator

```
gawk -v RS='[a-z]+\\n+' '
NR > 1 {
  printf "%s%s%s%s", sep, a[1], m[1], $0
  sep = ORS
}
{ split(RT,a,ORS,m) }
' ​file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e '2,$s/[a-z].*/===========================\n&/g' -e '/^$/d'  filename

output

abc
123
456
789
===========================
def
111
222
333
===========================
ghi
999
888
777
666
```